# Retrieve texts from a sales order by using RFC_READ_TEXT

Tags: c#, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-r3

I'm using SAP .NET Connector 3.0 to read data from SAP(R/3). I need to get some header texts from sales orders:
[image]

A lot of information I found regarding READ_TEXT function which can be used for this purpose.
Here you can find some **[sample](http://my.theobald-software.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/39/26/retrieve-texts-from-a-sales-order-by-using-rfc_read_text)** how to do it by using ERPConnect.
I'm trying to do the same and I have following function which returns IRfcTable:

```
static IRfcTable ReadFunction(string destName, int rowCount)
        {
            // get the destination
            RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(destName);

            IRfcFunction func = dest.Repository.CreateFunction("RFC_READ_TEXT");

            IRfcTable table = func.GetTable("TEXT_LINES");
            table.Insert();
            table.Insert();
            table.Insert();
            table.Insert();
            table[0].SetValue("TDOBJECT", "VBBK");
            table[1].SetValue("TDNAME", "3147856016");
            table[2].SetValue("TDID", "Z019");
            table[3].SetValue("TDSPRAS", "PL");
            func.Invoke(dest);
            return table;
        }
```

`VBBK` - means header objects, `3147856016` - sales order number, `Z019` - ID for EDI Supplier text field, `PL` - language.
As a result I'm retrieving some data, but field TDLINE is blank:

[image]
According to example this field should contain text.
Probably some parameters are incorrect. **[Here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/738776)** is a good post where I found how to obtain TDID parameter for each text field.
What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** According to `vwegert` answer below, code has been changed like:

```
        IRfcTable table = func.GetTable("TEXT_LINES");
        table.Insert();
        table[0].SetValue("TDOBJECT", "VBBK");
        table[0].SetValue("TDNAME", "3147856016");
        table[0].SetValue("TDID", "Z019");
        table[0].SetValue("TDSPRAS", "PL");
        func.Invoke(dest);
        return table;
```

Now parameters are correct. But `TDLINE` is still empty. Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function module needs the following parameters:

```
  TDOBJECT    TDNAME       TDID       TDSPRAS
  ----------- ------------ ---------- -------
1 VBRK        3147856016   Z019       PL
```

You are calling it with the following parameters:

```
  TDOBJECT    TDNAME       TDID       TDSPRAS
  ----------- ------------ ---------- -------
1 VBRK        
2             3147856016   
3                          Z019       
4                                     L
```

This won't work - the function module will take the line containing a `TDNAME`, add `TDBOJECT = 'DRAD'`, `TDID = 'LTXT'` and `TDSPRAS = SY-LANGU` and attempt to read that text. This will probably fail, resulting in the empty line you see. Also note that you need to supply the internal language designator, which is a single character.

Furthermore you are completely ignoring the `MESSAGES` parameter that will probably contain some messages that would have told you a lot about what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay! Really, no need to create new rows to put each parameter. But `TDLINE` is still empty. I've updated my question. Regarding `MESSAGES` - is it separate table like `TEXT_LINES`?

Comment: I checked `MESSAGES` and following system error there `Text 3147856016 ID Z019 language PT not found`. I assume, some search parameter is incorrect. And also I noticed, that error contains language `PT` instead of `PL`.

Comment: Yes. `TDLIN` is empty because of language. In my case `TDSPRAS = PL`, and system takes only first symbol. I've changed `TDSPRAS = L` and now I retrieved this text. I'm really appreciate your for help. You saved a lot of time for me. Without this ERROR MESSAGE I couldn't identify the issue. Now it works!

Comment: Which function can be used to create or change existing SAP texts? Let's say I have same TDID = Z019 on sales order header and would like to assign new text for it. Can you, please, recomment some RFC enabled function for that?

Comment: @mbigun That should be a separate question, I think - and not hidden in some comments...