# How to read multiple lines in RFC_READ_TEXT with one request?

Tags: saprfc

I am going through some problems, I need to access a large number of texts relating to the Purchase Order.

With the help of this topic([Retrieve texts from a sales order by using RFC_READ_TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906107/retrieve-texts-from-a-sales-order-by-using-rfc-read-text)), could use function RFC_READ_TEXT to access one of the purchase orders I needed.

But I need to access more than 22,000 requests per month. And according to the thread I mentioned I can only return one text at a time.

How could I do to extract a set of Purchase Order text with one request?

I really appreciate everyone's attention.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the option of writing your own function module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RFC_READ_TEXT` to read texts for more than one object in a single call. Just specify each additional object as an additional row in table parameter `TEXT_LINES`.

I wouldn't suggest reading 22,000 in a single call, however, but certainly more than 1 in a single call is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread at SCN where we Discussed this topic http://scn.sap.com/thread/3651641 .

It's pretty much what mjturner said , I just did not know how to do that requisition to sap RFC_READ_TEXT .

The tip is to use your OPTIONS parameter with the semicolon separator, it makes you pass like multiples less-than -72 -chars strings in the same string. See SCN thread to more details .

Sorry about my two account here too .

Bye